# c# Correct way to convert string value to decimal

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimalformat

I need convert the any value in format **"101.46"** to **decimal**.

```
string s = "101.46";
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
```

But the decimal final value is always **10146**. I need the format of the output value to be **101.46 as decimal**

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: Is that `.` treated ad a decimal or a thousands separator in your locale?

Comment: Brazil, i set Culture info to "pt-BR in web.config on my aspnet application, but without success.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Convert.ToDecimal` will use the currently executing thread's culture - and my guess is that in your case, that's a culture that uses `,` as the decimal separator rather than `.`. You just need to specify the right culture - which is often the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_InvariantCulture) - that's almost always the right culture to use for any strings that are intended to be machine-readable. (You should use the invariant culture for creating such strings too.)

I'd generally recommend using the static [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netframework-4.7.1) methods over `Convert.ToXyz` (as they're often more capable, and have `TryParse` options too), so while you *could* pass the invariant culture to `Convert.ToDecimal`, I'd use:

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current culture seems to use `,` as decimal separator, then you could use:

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    decimal d = decimal.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

If you want to use regular expression you can use as below,

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
}
```

#### If function returns true then

```
if(isNumeric(Yourvalue)){
  decimal value = decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex.... Maybe there is already a built in `TryParse` method??

Comment: This will help you for logging and set default values if a value is not a number. or Do certain operations. I use this static function first so I can write proper log. But Not everyone agrees with that. That's my way of coding @Igor

Comment: You can achieve all of that with [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx), there is no need for any of your custom methods.

Comment: @Igor you agree throwing exceptions makes your code slow? If we can catch that with regular expression why not do that?

Comment: Because you can achieve that with [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx). There is no need for a regular expression. The [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) has an `out` parameter (of type decimal) which is filled with a value if the method returns `true`, if it returns `false` then parsing did not succeed. No exception is thrown. As a bonus it also takes a formatting argument and you can pass a CultureInfo instance which is what the user requires in this case as that is why their code does not work.